# Can you remove the 'Windows Software Development Kit'

Tags: windows, installation, sdk, development-environment

For my development work, I have installed and am using the **Microsoft .NET SDK** from

```
../sdk-5.0.402-windows-x64-installer
```

and

```
../runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.11-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
```

The question is: can I uninstall the '**Windows Software Development Kit**'?

I don't recall ever installing it, did the Windows update install it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Visual studio installer .exe file.

1. Launch the installer
2. Click on "Modify"
3. Click on "Individual components", then search for the SDK you wish to uninstall, Uncheck it and finally click on "Modify"
   enter image description here

Cheers